# In Jenkins, Print shell script to both console log and to a file in the same time

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, pipeline

I have a job in Jenkins with a shell script that I want to save its output to a file and in the same time print to console, is that possible?

The shell script is doing `docker login` and `docker run`(this will pull the image too) and I want the output to be saved into a file and also printed in real time (printing the file content later on won't have the same effect)

Can someone assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tee`.

```
<command> 2>&1 | tee output.log
```

eg:

```
./docker_exec.sh 2>&1 | tee output.log
```

Answer (score 0):

In shell script to output your result in console and store in some file, you can do:

```
echo '<whatever you want to output>' >> <filename>
```

Comment: This prints the output of a shell script?